# Nodejs module extends with other module

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi i have parent module like this.

```
// usermgmt.js

var usermgmt = function () {};

usermgmt.prototype.test = function () {
    return "test";
};

usermgmt.private = function () {
    return "private";
};

module.exports = new usermgmt();
```

and a Child prototype class like this.

```
// authentication.js
var usermgmt = require('./usermgmt');

var authentication = function () {};

authentication.prototype.callParent = function () {
    usermgmt.private();
};

module.exports = new authentication();
```

How i implement inheritance? I searched by google but no solution works for me.

Comment: For normal inheritance, you would export the constructor, not an instance.  Also, is there any reason you're doing things the old-fashioned way instead of using the `class` keyword?  There are ways to hack around this, but I'd prefer not to hack when there is a normal way of doing things.

Comment: Have you an example for nodejs and module.export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jfriend00 said, I write these functions with `class` keyword which is a **syntactic sugar** for your code!

`usermgmt.js`

```
// usermgmt.js

class usermgmt {
  constructor() {

  }

  test() {
    return "test";
  }

  private() {
    return "private";
  }
}

module.exports = usermgmt;
```

Write authentication like this.

`authentication.js`

```
// authentication.js
var Usermgmt = require('./usermgmt.js');

class authentication extends Usermgmt {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  callParent() {
    console.log(this.private());
  }

  authFunction() {
    console.log(':: authFunction ::');
    this.callParent();
  }
}

module.exports = authentication;
```

And usage for authentication will be:

```
var Authentication = require('./authentication.js');

let auth = new Authentication();

auth.callParent();

auth.authFunction();

console.log(auth.test());
```

1) Use `class` and `extends` syntax which is easier.

2) Return Class and not its instance

Comment: i stuck on the next thing. I want to call method in another method but i get Cannot read property 'callmethod' of null

i called it with this.callmethod(); in a method of the class

Comment: I add some examples. Good luck. @user3807340

Answer (score 3):

Here's a typical way to export a base class and then import it and inherit from it using the more modern syntax:

```
// a.js
class A {
   constructor() {
   }
   testA() {
      return "testA";
   }
}

module.exports = A;
```

Then, in a separate file:

```
// b.js
const A = require('./a.js');

class B extends A {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    testB() {
        return "testB";
    }
}


let x = new B();
x.testA();           // "testA" - this is inherited obviously
x.testB();           // "testB"
```